# Wait for react props received from parent to update inside a childs function

Tags: reactjs

I have a function that Is executed in componentDidMount() , because it does an API call, and I need the info received for the render.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        email: this.props.email
    });
    this.getPermissionsList();
    this.getPermissionsValue(); //this one
}
```

Now, this function has the following issue

```
 getPermissionsValue(){
        console.log('/user/'+this.props.userId+'/permission') //At the moment of the execution, this.props.userId is empty
        API.get('/user'+this.props.userId+'/permission')
            .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            this.setState({
                permissionValue : response.data
            }, () => {
                console.log(this.state.permissionValue)
            });

        })
    }
```

But in my render, I can see the this.props.userId value.

```
    render(){
       return  <p>{this.props.userId}</p>  
}
```

How can I wait for that prop before rendering?

**EDIT**: This is how the prop is being sent to the child from the parent

In the parent component I have a child component in the render

```
<EditUserModal ...a lot of props.... userId={this.state.rowId} email={this.state.selectedMail} handleChangePass={this.handleChangePass} ....more props..../>
```

That rowId is assigned this way in the parent component:

In my render I have this

```
<Table
                     className="table"
                     filterable={['Email']}
                     itemsPerPage={8}
                     currentPage={0}
                     sortable={true}
                >
                    {users.map((row) => {
                        return (

                            <Tr className={row.className}>
                                <Td column="Email">{row.email}</Td>
                                <Td column="Edit" ><FontAwesomeIcon className="editIcon" onClick={()=> this.showModal(row.id, row.email)} icon={faEdit} /></Td> 
                            </Tr>

                        )
                    })}
                </Table>
```

where the onclick calls

```
showModal(rowId, rowEmail) {
    this.setState({
        showModal: true,
        rowId: rowId,
        selectedMail: rowEmail
    }, () => {
        // console.log("clicked show modal")
        // console.log(this.state.showModal)
    });

}
```

And thats where the rowId state value is set

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding the question, can you show how you get `this.props.userId` and how you pass it to this component

Comment: seems here is a same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50094331/react-app-componentdidmount-not-getting-props-from-parent

Comment: @Carr i will update the question with more details

Comment: @Carr updated with more info

Comment: I did a componentDidUpdate() , testing some stuff but might work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your scenario, I think there are a lot of chances that `componentDidMount` in your child component fires before `this.props.userId` get value. (I think your `user` array comes from an API call too). You can look into [discussion in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50094331/react-app-componentdidmount-not-getting-props-from-parent) to see why it could happen.

My suggestion is, instead of putting the API call in the `componentDidMount()`, put it into `componentDidUpdate()`, if you do the comparison, you don't need to worry about calling the API multiple times. It's a typical usage recommended in the [official doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
  if (this.props.userID !== prevProps.userID) {
    yourAPI(this.props.userID);
  }
}
```

Also here is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47008964/4365123) I wrote before trying to compare where to deploy the API calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the second argument of setState:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
    email: this.props.email
  }, () => {
    this.getPermissionsList();
    this.getPermissionsValue(); //this one
  });
}
```

This ensures that the state gets set first, -then- calls the other two methods.